# 3 UIPicker view in single view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have 3 picker view in my view controller
the picker1 contain contain 2 row Audio and Video.picker2 contain product type,if audio is selected in picker1 then picker2 should populate with (`transistor,walkman,ipod`) and if video is selected in picker1 then picker2 should populate with (`tv,screen,monitor`) and if walkman is selected in picker2 then picker3 should populate with (`sony,philips,jbl`).
i am confused with the if condition....

```
if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Audio"] && [[audioProduct objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"walkman"])
{
    NSLog(@"Audio and walkman");
    modelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman1",@"walkman2",@"walman3", nil];
        [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];   
}
else if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Audio"] && [[audioProduct objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"mp3"]) {
modelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"mp3",@"mp3", @"mp3",@"mp3",nil];

    [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to load picker2 and picker 3 conditionally, as follows:

```
picker1Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Audio",@"Video", nil]
if ([[picker1array objectAtIndex:[picker1 selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"Audio"])
{
    picker2Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"transistor",@"walkman",@"ipod", nil];
}
else {
    picker2Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"tv",@"screen",@"monitor", nil];
}
 [picker2 reloadAllComponents];  

if ([[picker2array objectAtIndex:[picker2 selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"walkman"]){
   picker3Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sony",@"philips",@"jbl", nil];
} 
[picker3 reloadAllComponents];
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code.

in .h file please declare

```
NSMutableArray *randCatSel;
    NSMutableArray *randSubCatSel;
    NSMutableArray *randItemSel;
    UIPickerView *packerView;
```

and in .m file write this code.

```
- (void)fetchedData{

    randCatSel =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Audio",@"Video", nil];

    packerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 200)];
    packerView.delegate=self;
    packerView.dataSource=self;
    packerView.tag=1;
    [self.view addSubview:packerView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        return [randCatSel count];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        return [randSubCatSel count];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==3)
    {
        return [randItemSel count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        return [randCatSel objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        return [randSubCatSel objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==3)
    {
        return [randItemSel objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }



}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        if(randSubCatSel.count>0)
        {
            randSubCatSel=nil;
        }

        if([[randCatSel objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"Audio"])
        {
                    randSubCatSel=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Transistor",@"walkman",@"ipod", nil];
        }
        else
        {
                    randSubCatSel=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TV",@"Screen",@"Monitor", nil];
        }

        [packerView removeFromSuperview];
        packerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 200)];
        packerView.delegate=self;
        packerView.dataSource=self;
        packerView.tag=2;
        [self.view addSubview:packerView];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        //do coding according to randSubCatSel for randItemSel
    }
}
```

please note that this is sample code for your requirement. you need to make changes accordingly.
i hope this code will help you.